# Angular2 error after updating to Typescript 2.1

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just uploaded my Angular2 project to the latest version of Typescript (from 2.0.3 to 2.1.4).
When launching my app I do get the following error :

```
zone.js:242 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token ;
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:242:26)
        at Zone.run (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43)
        at http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:520:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:275:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:35)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25)
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angular__platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angular__platform-browser-dynamic/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:9000/assets/app/bootstrap.ts
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:242:26)
        at Zone.run (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43)
        at http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:520:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:275:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:35)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25)
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angular__platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9000/assets/lib/angular__platform-browser-dynamic/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:9000/assets/app/bootstrap.ts
```

I have no idea what's wrong here though

EDIT:
My bootstrap.ts file

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { AppModule } from './app.module'

// enableProdMode()
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Comment: can you add plnkr of your code.  may be angular don't support typescript 2.1 at this moment because in there quickstart they are using typescript": "~2.0.10"

Comment: Use 2.0.10 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13670#issuecomment-269140547

Comment: Make sure to update "ts-node": "^1.7.0"

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be on your bootstrap.ts file, if you could paste it's code here it could help.

I had a problem similar to this when upgrading from typescript 2 to 2.1.4. If I am not mistake, the error was also with this token ;
At that time I was trying to use a dev version from Typescript 2.1, but I thought there was something wrong with the version, being dev and all.

But the same error ocurred when upgrading to the stable 2.1.4. And, as I can remember, the error was because there was some commented code on the last lines of the file. I removed this commented code and it started working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after updating Typescript (from 2.0.3 to 2.1.4).

The error was caused by some commented out code at the bottom of the .ts file. I was able to see the syntax error in the .js file that it was transpiled to.

Removing the commented out code from the bottom of the affected .ts file fixed the issue for me.